# What can we say about class number of a number field using class number formula?

Tags: field-theory, algebraic-number-theory, riemann-zeta, zeta-functions

Let $K$ be a number field with Dirichlet zeta function $\zeta_K(s), $ we have the class number formula: $$\lim_{s \to 1^+} (s-1)\zeta_K(s) =  \cfrac{2^{r_1}(2\pi)^{r_2}Rh}{m\sqrt{(|\Delta)|}}$$
 where $r_1$ is the number of real embeddings of the field, $r_2$ for complex -*nonconjugate*- ones; $R$ for the regulator of $K, h$ is the class number of $K$, $m$ is the number of roots of unity in $K$ and $\Delta$ is the discriminant of $K$.

Using this formula, what can we say about $h$ and can we give a lower or upper bound for it?

Comment: What you wrote is not an equation. Further its too vague, bounds for which fields under what restrictions?

Comment: @ReneSchipperus there was just an equals sign missing, easy to fix.  Now it is an equation.

Comment: The question is still hopelessly vague.

Comment: When $K$ is imaginary quadratic the regulator term is $1$ and the residue formula becomes $(2\pi)h/(m\sqrt{|\Delta|})$, which is usually $\pi h/\sqrt{|\Delta|}$ since $m = 2$ except in two cases ($K = \mathbf Q(i)$ where $m = 4$ and $K = \mathbf Q(\sqrt{-3})$ where $m = 6$). There are other ways of computing the residue and this leads to a concrete formula for the class number of imaginary quadratic fields in terms of sums with Jacobi symbols.

Comment: In chapter 4 of Washington's book on cyclotomic fields the class number formula for a cyclotomic field $\mathbf Q(\zeta_m)$ and its maximal real subfield $\mathbf Q(\zeta_m + \zeta_m^{-1})$ are compared to each other in order to deduce that the class number of $\mathbf Q(\zeta_m)$ grows with $m$: there are only finitely many cyclotomic fields with any particular class number.  Later in the book he makes this explicit by determining all cyclotomic fields with class number $1$.

Comment: In Chapter 5 of Washington's book he finds a $p$-adic analogue of the class number formula totally real number fields (a reasonable restriction, since there's no $p$-adic substitute for the factor $(2\pi)^{r_2}$), where the classical regulator is replaced by a $p$-adic regulator using $p$-adic logarithms. The resulting formula can be used to deduce some $p$-divisibility properties of the class number by $p$-adic analysis ($p$ divides $h$ if and only if $|h|_p < 1$).

Comment: @ReneSchipperus I don't see why the question is "hopelessly vague".  It is not unreasonable to wonder what the point of such a formula is when it is called a "class number formula" but doesn't directly give you a formula for $h$ alone (except in the imaginary quadratic case where $R = 1$, and the boring case $K = \mathbf Q$).

Comment: I don't see what the damage is in trying to expose to the OP some useful facts that are related to his/her question. Further, this is Keith Conrad. The last thing the man needs is to 'show off knowledge'.

Comment: @ReneSchipperus I am addressing the OP's question by pointing out some ways the class number formula is used. (What I wrote is known to many people who have studied algebraic number theory in more depth than the OP, who is just learning the basics now.) If anyone else wants to offer a more detailed response, they are welcome to do that.  Criticizing the OP for the question in this case does not seem productive. That is the end of what I will say on this matter.

Comment: @KCd, thank you for your valuable contributions.

Comment: @ReneSchipperus In my understanding, the OP asks "using this formula, what can we say about $h$?". Then he asks about bounds as a sort of follow-up question, almost like he/she thinks this could be an application of such formula